# Calculate the missing row value from previous non-missing value

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

It is a simple exercise in Excel but don't know how to do it in Pyspark

I have a growth rate in a time series pattern.

```
Period, Rate, value
1, ., 100
2, 0.01,
3, 0.02,
4, 0.01
```

So the value is only available in period 1. All the other values should be calculated as follows:

Period 2: 100*(1+0.01) = 101

Period 3: 101*(1+0.02)

Period 2 is essentially the period 1 value as base combined with rate in period 2 to calculate. So on and so forth.

It is quite easy to do it in Excel but don't know how to do it in Pyspark.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would it be possible to to do the calculations in Python and then transform the result into a Pyspark dataframe? This kind of task is difficult to parallelize, and Spark's main usage is to do things in parallel...

Comment: The problem is that the data set is in delta format. But for Python, can you point to me a direction how to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `log` and `exp` to get the total value until that period. Your value is a multiply aggregation.

```
1, 0.01, 100 * (1 + 0.01)
2, 0.01, 100 * (1 + 0.01) * (1 + 0.01)
...
n, 0.01, 100 * (1 + 0.01)^n
```

So, take a `log`, `sum` the values `log(1 + 0.01)` over window and take back to `exp`.

```
value = 100

w = Window.orderBy('Period')
df.withColumn('value', value * exp(sum(log(col('Rate') + 1).cast('decimal(38, 20)')).over(w))).show()

+------+----+------------------+
|Period|Rate|             value|
+------+----+------------------+
|     1| 0.0|             100.0|
|     2|0.01|             101.0|
|     3|0.01|            102.01|
|     4|0.01|103.03010000000002|
|     5|0.01|        104.060401|
|     6|0.01|105.10100501000001|
|     7|0.01|106.15201506010001|
|     8|0.01|107.21353521070101|
|     9|0.01|108.28567056280802|
|    10|0.01|109.36852726843608|
|    11|0.01|110.46221254112045|
|    12|0.01|111.56683466653166|
|    13|0.01|112.68250301319698|
|    14|0.01|113.80932804332895|
|    15|0.01|114.94742132376223|
|    16|0.01|116.09689553699987|
+------+----+------------------+
```

Or, use the `aggregate` function by making the rates to a list.

```
value = 100

df.withColumn('temp', expr("aggregate(collect_list(Rate + 1) OVER (ORDER BY Period), 1D, (acc, x) -> acc * x)")) \
  .withColumn('value', col('temp') * value).show()

+------+----+------------------+------------------+
|Period|Rate|             value|              temp|
+------+----+------------------+------------------+
|     1| 0.0|             100.0|               1.0|
|     2|0.01|             101.0|              1.01|
|     3|0.01|            102.01|            1.0201|
|     4|0.01|103.03009999999999|          1.030301|
|     5|0.01|        104.060401|        1.04060401|
|     6|0.01|      105.10100501|      1.0510100501|
|     7|0.01|106.15201506009998|    1.061520150601|
|     8|0.01|107.21353521070098|1.0721353521070098|
|     9|0.01|108.28567056280801|  1.08285670562808|
|    10|0.01|109.36852726843608|1.0936852726843609|
|    11|0.01|110.46221254112045|1.1046221254112045|
|    12|0.01|111.56683466653166|1.1156683466653166|
|    13|0.01|112.68250301319698|1.1268250301319698|
|    14|0.01|113.80932804332895|1.1380932804332895|
|    15|0.01|114.94742132376223|1.1494742132376223|
|    16|0.01|116.09689553699987|1.1609689553699987|
+------+----+------------------+------------------+
```

Both of the examples have a precision problem in the 4th period.